# Open CSS/Javascript collapsible when "find on page" from browser hits

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the example from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp) to create a series of collapsible sections on a single html page. The collapsible is made as a combination of CSS and some embedded JavaScript code.

Suppose that the visitor of the page wants to search on the page using the "Find in page" (CTRL-F) function of the browser. If a hit is found, the browser will move to the hit (and highlight it), but it remains hidden in the collapsible. How would I go about to automagically open that collapsible when the search hits?

Limitation: I don't want to use external libraries like jQuery. The html page should end up on a local drive and should work without internet access.

Simplified code from w3schools is given below. Suppose the user hits CTRL-F and searches for `supercalifragilistic`, the browser will highlight the first occurence and move focus to it. But it stays hidden in the collapsible. Is there a way to open up the collapsible following a successful search?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .collapsible {
      background-color: #777;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    
    .active, .collapsible:hover {
      background-color: #555;
    }
    
    .collapsible:after {
      content: '\002B';
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .active:after {
      content: "\2212";
    }
    
    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Animated Collapsibles</h2>
    
    <p>A Collapsible:</p>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
    <div class="content">
          <p>Collapsible 1 text supercalifragilistic.</p>
        </div>
           
        
        <script>
        var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you read the page I linked you'll see that linking us elsewhere should be a last resort. Dropping a short demo of that code _here_ would be easy and save us all some hassle.

Comment: The duplicate above doesn't exactly answer your question, but it explains why it's essentially unanswerable.

Comment: It's not that I want to listen *if* the user presses CTRL-F and what she searches for, but if there is a way that when the browser highlights the item found and moves the page to bring the first occurrence in view, the collapsible in which it is hidden can be opened. So I thought it was more a "follow focus"-thing than "capture a search term"...

Comment: Those two things are closely tied together. You can't have one without the other.

Comment: So my only option is to provide my own search bar on the page and include tags in the html code, right?

Comment: That's a common approach. See Bitbucket's diff tool and the JCE editor for Joomla as examples of site components that capture Ctrl-f inputs and do local search themselves.